# ADO.Net EF, Mapping Issue

Tags: database, entity-framework, inheritance, ado.net, mapping

I have the following Entities and the issue I am having is that I have a type Game which inherits from MediaItem. I have passed a collection of Game to a view and I want to be able to display the Games Rating (Stored inside LibraryItemRating) as Rating. Currently I cannot do this, as when I get to Game.Libraryitems I have a collection..

I want LibraryItems association with MediaItem to be 1 -- *   and not   * -- 1.
The only referential constraint which is sensible is Principal: MediaItem (MediaItemID) and Dependent: (MediaItem). When this is set I can only have the * -- 1 relationship, otherwise I get these two errors:

> Multiplicity is not valid in Role
>   'LibraryItem' in relationship
>   'MediaItemLibraryItem'. Because the
>   Dependent Role properties are not the
>   key properties, the upper bound of the
>   multiplicity of the Dependent Role
>   must be *.

and

> Multiplicity is not valid in role
>   'MediaItem' in relationship
>   'MediaItemLibraryItem'. Valid values
>   for multiplicity for Principal Role
>   are '0..1' or '1'.

Any help would be appreciated! Here is a screenshot:[image]

Note: MediaItem(MediaItemID) maps to LibraryItem(MediaItem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have that multiplicity with your current setup. Your current setup says: *One MediaItem can be in multiple LibraryItems.* It means that `MediaItem` is principal and `LibraryItem` is dependent and because of that it has FK property `MediaItem`. If you want the reverse relation the meaning will be: *One LibraryItem can have multiple MediaItems.* In such case `LibraryItem` will become principal and `MediaItem` will became dependent and because of that you also must change your entities:

- Delete relation between `LibraryItem` and `MediaItem`. It should  also remove navigation properties on both sides.
- Delete `MediaItem` property in `LibraryItem` entity.
- Add `LibraryItem` FK property to `MediaItem` entity
- Create new association between `LibraryItem` and `MediaItem` and map referential constraints to fulfill your needs.